# How to Alias a query in SP and use the result throughout the Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

m writing a stored procedure in which i have 4 select queries

i want some data from first select query to use in where clause of rest of three queries.

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.[Order] WHERE (dbo.[Order].[CreatedOn]<(GetDate()-7)) AND ((@OrderId IS NULL)OR(dbo.[Order].[OrderId] BETWEEN (@OrderId) AND (@orderId+100))) ORDER BY dbo.[Order].[OrderId]

SELECT * FROM dbo.[OrderItem] WHERE  dbo.[OrderItem].[OrderId] IN(SELECT TOP 100 dbo.[Order].[OrderId] FROM dbo.[Order] WHERE (dbo.[Order].[CreatedOn]<(GetDate()-7)) AND ((@OrderId IS NULL)OR(dbo.[Order].[OrderId] BETWEEN (@OrderId) AND (@orderId+100))))

SELECT  dbo.OrderItemAddOn.* FROM dbo.OrderItemAddOn INNER JOIN dbo.MenuItemAddOn ON dbo.OrderItemAddOn.MenuItemAddOnId = dbo.MenuItemAddOn.MenuItemAddOnId           
   INNER JOIN dbo.MenuAddOn ON dbo.MenuItemAddOn.MenuAddOnId = dbo.MenuAddOn.MenuAddOnId          
   INNER JOIN dbo.OrderItem ON dbo.OrderItemAddOn.OrderItemId = dbo.OrderItem.OrderItemId  
   AND dbo.OrderItem.OrderId IN(SELECT TOP 100 dbo.[Order].[OrderId] FROM dbo.[Order] WHERE (dbo.[Order].[CreatedOn]<(GetDate()-7)) AND ((@OrderId IS NULL)OR(dbo.[Order].[OrderId] BETWEEN (@OrderId) AND (@orderId+100)))) ORDER BY dbo.OrderItemAddOn.OrderItemAddOnId, dbo.OrderItemAddOn.OrderItemId            

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM    dbo.OrderItemModifier INNER JOIN dbo.OrderItem ON dbo.OrderItemModifier.OrderItemId = dbo.OrderItem.OrderItemId 
    AND dbo.OrderItem.OrderId IN (SELECT TOP 100 dbo.[Order].[OrderId] FROM dbo.[Order] WHERE (dbo.[Order].[CreatedOn]<(GetDate()-7)) AND ((@OrderId IS NULL)OR(dbo.[Order].[OrderId] BETWEEN (@OrderId) AND (@orderId+100))))          
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MenuModifierGroup ON dbo.OrderItemModifier.MenuModifierGroupId = dbo.MenuModifierGroup.MenuModifierGroupId ORDER BY OrderItemModifier.OrderItemId
```

If you notice this query

```
SELECT OrderId FROM dbo.[Order] WHERE (dbo.[Order].[CreatedOn]<(GetDate()-7)) AND ((@OrderId IS NULL)OR(dbo.[Order].[OrderId] BETWEEN (@OrderId) AND (@orderId+100))) ORDER BY dbo.[Order].[OrderId]
```

is getting repeated as i want the OrderIds from this query. the queries above are definitely wrong approach.. i want to alias this query and want to use the same result in all my queries.. can u guys please help.

what we can do is alias this query and use the same result in all four queries too.. thats also a good solution.. but how to alias the queries in SPs..

Comment: You can keep result from first query into temp table. Then these temp table be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options that you could research:

- Temp tables
- Table values variable
- View
- Common table expression
- UDF or stored procedure returning a table

Though I can't tell too much about your case from the queries you provided, a simple starting point would be with a temporary table called #recent_orders to hold the results from your subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.[Order] 
INTO #recent_orders
WHERE (dbo.[Order].[CreatedOn]<(GetDate()-7)) 
AND (
   (@OrderId IS NULL)
    OR
   (dbo.[Order].[OrderId] BETWEEN (@OrderId) AND (@orderId+100))
) 
ORDER BY dbo.[Order].[OrderId]
```

You can then reference it in subsequent queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[OrderItem]
WHERE  dbo.[OrderItem].[OrderId] IN(SELECT [OrderId] FROM #recent_orders)
```

Comment: Good explanation Mikey.. thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
select column_1 into #tmp_first_result
from FIRST_QUERY WHERE ....


select *
from SECOND_QUERY INNER JOIN #tmp_first_result T ON (......)
```

You can re-use #tmp_first_result for any other query.

Answer (score 0):

If the query you want to alias is used in different stored procedures, one of the solution is to use the [Inline Table-Valued Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294.aspx). In your case:

```
CREATE GetOrderID(@Date Date, @OrderId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
SELECT OrderId FROM dbo.[Order] WHERE (dbo.[Order].[CreatedOn]<(@Date-7)) AND ((@OrderId IS NULL)OR(dbo.[Order].[OrderId] BETWEEN (@OrderId) AND (@orderId+100))) ORDER BY dbo.[Order].[OrderId]
)
```

Now You can use this function (last of your query, for example):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM    dbo.OrderItemModifier INNER JOIN dbo.OrderItem ON dbo.OrderItemModifier.OrderItemId = dbo.OrderItem.OrderItemId 
    AND dbo.OrderItem.OrderId IN (SELECT TOP 100 FROM dbo.GetOrderID(GetDate(), @OrderID))          
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MenuModifierGroup ON dbo.OrderItemModifier.MenuModifierGroupId = dbo.MenuModifierGroup.MenuModifierGroupId ORDER BY OrderItemModifier.OrderItemId
```

Sorry, I didn't tested this code, it's just for example.